# AWS CLI PartiQL INSERT statement returns "ExecuteStatement operation: Requested resource not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, partiql

I'm following the instructions in the [AWS developer guide tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedDynamoDB.html) and just changed the names of the attributes. I can't seem to make the `INSERT INTO tablename VALUE` statement work.

I created the table `resourceLock` & ensured it was fully created (`TableStatus` = `ACTIVE`):

```
aws dynamodb create-table --profile free --output table \
    --table-name resourceLock \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=resourceType,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=resourceName,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=resourceType,KeyType=HASH \
        AttributeName=resourceName,KeyType=RANGE \
    --billing-mode=PAY_PER_REQUEST \
--table-class=STANDARD \
```

[image]

Then, I tried to run the below statement:

```
aws dynamodb execute-statement  --statement "INSERT INTO resourcelock VALUE {'resourceName':'dev', 'resourceType':'environment'}"  --profile free
```

Which gave me the error:

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Requested resource not found

I've tried a number of variations on the syntax but I can't seem to get it to work from the cli.

I can add items via the AWS Console so not sure what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: You're using `resourcelock` and not `resourceLock`; it's case sensitive. Try `aws dynamodb execute-statement  --statement "INSERT INTO resourceLock VALUE {'resourceName':'dev', 'resourceType':'environment'}"  --profile free`. Does that work?

Comment: Thank you! I put an answer in too which I tried before yours. Could you undelete your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer please @ErmiyaEskandary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table is created with the name `resourceLock` (upper-case L), but the `execute-statement` command is using `resourcelock` (lower-case L).

Table names are case-sensitive in DynamoDB, so this should work:

```
aws dynamodb execute-statement  --statement "INSERT INTO resourceLock VALUE {'resourceName':'dev', 'resourceType':'environment'}"  --profile free
```

Comment: Thank you!. I should stop doing this on a Sunday night :-D How obvious!

Comment: @PreetSangha More than welcome! Enjoy using AWS :)